# Operator norm equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces such that $T: X \to Y$ is a linear continuous transformation. I'd like to prove that 
$$
\sup_{||x|| \leq 1} ||T(x)|| = \sup_{||x|| < 1} ||T(x)||. 
$$

1. It's clear that $$\sup_{||x|| \leq 1} ||T(x)|| \geq \sup_{||x|| < 1} ||T(x)||,$$ since $\{||T(x)||: ||x|| < 1 \} \subset \{||T(x)||: ||x|| \leq 1 \}$.
2. However, I can't manage to prove $$\sup_{||x|| \leq 1} ||T(x)|| \leq \sup_{||x|| < 1} ||T(x)||.$$ Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x \in X$ with $||x|| = 1$, define an arbitrary sequence $(x_n) \in X^\mathbb{N}$ with $||x_n|| < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, e.g. $x_n := \frac{n-1}{n}x$. Then, since both $T$ and $||\cdot||$ are continuous and $x_n \rightarrow x$, we have $||T(x_n)|| \rightarrow ||T(x)||$, and since $||T(x_n)|| \leq \sup_{||y||<1} ||T(y)||$, we obtain $||T(x)|| \leq \sup_{||y||<1}||T(y)||$ for all $x \in X$ with $||x|| = 1$. Now, for $||x|| < 1$, the inequality obviously remains true, which proves the statement.

Comment: This answer works fine but there are some comments. First, you aren't using continuity of $T$ or $\|\cdot\|$ with your specific choice of $x_n$ at all, just linearity and positive homogeneity. You also don't need to divide in to the case $\|x\|=1$ and $\|x\| <1$, the first argument works for both in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Take a sequence $x_n$ with $\|x_n\| \leq 1$ and $\|Tx_n\| \to \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|Tx\|$. Then consider $y_n = \frac{n}{n+1} x_n$. We have $\|y_n\| < 1$ and $\|Ty_n\| = \frac{n}{n+1} \|Tx_n\| \to \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|Tx\|$ so that $\sup_{\|x\|<1} \|Tx\| \geq \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|Tx\|$.

Comment: I apologize, but I was mistaken about a hypothesis. I have edited the question.

Comment: For linear operators, continuous and bounded mean the same thing. (Note that here $T$ bounded means that there is a constant $C$ such that $\|Tx\| \leq C\|x\|$ here and not that $T$ has bounded image).

Comment: If I understood it correctly, $T(x_n)$ is an increasing sequence, therefore $T(y_n)$ is also an increasing sequence always below it. So it'd give us that $\sup_{||x|| < 1}||T(x)|| \leq \sup_{||x|| \leq 1} ||T(x)||$, no?

Comment: Nope, $Tx_n$ is valued in a normed space so it makes no sense to say its increasing. $\|Tx_n\|$ is real valued but also need not be increasing. The (very standard) idea is to show that you can find a sequence in $\{ x : \|x\|<1\}$ such that $\|Tx_n\| \to \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|Tx\|$. Then you must have $\sup_{\|x\| < 1} \|Tx\| \geq  \|Tx_n\|$ for each $n$ so $\sup_{\|x\| < 1} \|Tx\| \geq \lim \|Tx_n\| = \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|Tx\|$.